# Playwright freezing when running in background with multiple threads

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to run playwright script in multi threaded mode but whenever the playwright browsers go to background they freeze
Is there anyway I can fix this? I already added these args but no luck
`--disable-background-timer-throttling`, `--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows`, `--disable-hang-monitor`

I need all threads to work simultaneously